# How to buy Skyrim in a country where Steam version is not avaliable and there is no retail?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I'm from Tbilisi, Georgia, and steam says that game is not available for my country. There are no "official" shops here to buy retail. On the nearest Russian online shops I see a notice stating that license is for Russia and countries of the CIS (Georgia is not among them from 2008). So what are my options? How can I get a licensed version of this long awaited game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get gifted a copy by someone somewhere else over Steam.

You can buy it from somewhere like Amazon.

The game is Steamworks, so it requires Steam to be run on PC. It isn't available to BUY in Georgia perhaps, but it will run (source: I traded countless Russians GTA Complete when it was on sale since it was not available in Russia)

Comment: Yes, but when i bought several keys from russian stores, and had to return them, because steam didnt allow to activate the game, because of region :(

Answer (score 1):

Amazon delivery? That would work if they deliver to your country

Comment: Thank you for answer..Yes, it would work, but i want digital copy more, associated with some account..Think steam is only option here(that is NOT an option) So i think i'll have to buy from amazon....

Answer (score 0):

im not totally sure how this works, but im pretty sure that any copy you get from any where will try and register through steam.

im not sure if steam checks your country at that point or not, but if it does and it blocks you, i dont see any way around no matter where you buy it from.

hopefully someone can expaned on this.

Answer (score -1):

You can accress other steam regions by using the direct URL

eg.

http://store.steampowered.com/?cc=US (for US)

This is a useful tool to check the prices in three English speaking regions:

http://www.steamprices.com/

There are problems with payment within these regions though. Unless you have a credit card where the billing address is in that counrty it might be difficult to get steam to procoess your order.

Do a search for how to pay for games on steam in a different region. Here are a few quick sites I found:

Sorry can only post 2 hyper-links to avoid spam

gamers-underground.com/games-general/31856-how-save-money-steam-using-vpn.html
coflash.com/steam/

Good luck.

P.s.

Here is a link to the Steam TOS:

store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/

You can see for yourself if it is against it or not. As far as I know I have been told my Steam Help to use another region than that in which I live becuase my credit card is registered in another country. Seems strange to me that they would suggest the braking of their TOS in a help enquiry.

Can you please quote where it says it's against their TOS? I founbd this forum post but things aren't 100% clear:

forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2100398

By they way I don't suggest doing anything that could lock your account so if it is so that it can be locked becuase of my advise please disregard it. I hope that I may have provided some way to help the OP with a solution to their question.

Comment: Let me clarify, using a VPN to buy a game in a different country, than you are in is against their rules, and is ban able.